# Canvas crashes when a bitmap/circle/text or anything is drawn and the user switches to landscape or portrait

Tags: android, canvas, switch-statement, landscape, portrait

I pretty much just have a canvas on my android app that has a text in the center of the screen (I tried a set position like 100,100 or like canvas.getWidth()/2, canvas.getHeight()/2) when the user switches the mode whether from portrait to landscape or from landscape to portrait during that switch it crashes and reports a null pointer exception. When nothing is drawn on the canvas I can freely switch between the two modes. How can I stop the crashing ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this attribute in Android manifest file, into activity tag

```
  android:configChanges="orientation"
```

Then may be your problem solve because when orientation is changing that time activity is restarting and all object having null reference..